# LWJGL colors with alpha are not rendering in correct way

Tags: java, lwjgl

Any ideas how to fix this glow effect?

```
GlStateManager.pushMatrix();
GL11.glColor4f(1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F);
        
GlStateManager.enableBlend();
GlStateManager.blendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
GlStateManager.bindTexture(image.getId());
GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_QUADS, 0, wr.getVertexCount());
```

[Effect of the code <- here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8DSW.png)

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmggs.png)

Comment: Use just GL_ONE for the second blendFunc parameter.

Comment: It didn't work, result: https://imgur.com/a/mPminfb